# With VS 2010 create ASP.NET composite custom server control with JQuery (CDN) as embedded resource?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, custom-server-controls

First time asking a question so sorry if incorrect.

After beating my head against the wall, and with no hair to pad it I am finally asking for direction. Most books, posts and articles on what I am trying to do are at least 2 years old and don't cover VS 2010.

Can someone point me to a site/book/whatever that gives meaningful examples of what I have asked in the title?

I am trying to create an ASP.NET custom web control, using VS 2010 and ASP.NET, and using an embedded rousource that is a javascript file with a simple jquery routine that attaches a click event onto a checkbox.

Trying it on my own all weekend I have successfullly gotten a web user control to work without having the script be embedded, but can't seem to get the references to work correctly when using a custom server control.

I can list the simple code but don't want to overwelm the post with code that they have seen over the years.

Thanks for your patience, and I hope to be able to contribute more on some levels.

Thanks,

FSBarker

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help a lot with your problem http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/04/29/creating-custom-asp-net-server-controls-with-embedded-javascript.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I have indeed read that article. That much of it I have gotten working. Again, it is 4 years old so there are changes to creating references etc, and I seem to get in trouble with the embedding and jquery but it did help clear some up.

Comment: I don;t think that there are much changes, asp.net was already present at 2007 and now besides the new .net 4.0 runtime not much has changed.

Comment: Thanks again Programista for the quick response yesterday. Actually, there are some changes with using Ajax, JQuery and other client side script with Server Controls, and I finally found the article I was looking for. It is here: http://winthusiasm.com/Articles/HtmlEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx